# Run a Powershell command as an Administrator - Commands themself won't load

Tags: c#, powershell, administrator

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var newProcessInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
            newProcessInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe";
            newProcessInfo.Verb = "runas";
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(newProcessInfo);
            newProcessInfo.Arguments = @"sfc /scannow";
        }
    }
}
```

So my code works up to a point.  you click the windows form application button and it will run windows Powershell in 64bit as an administrator but won't run a .ps1 script "c:\path\script.ps1" or the command directly written out like the "sfc /scannow" above.

I was reading that the powershell commands won't work sometimes if the "Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted" isn't loaded somewhere in the beginning of the code.

Please help!  I have been looking everywhere for an answer.

Comment: `[...]\SysWOW64\[...]\powershell.exe` is *32-bit* powershell

Comment: why don't you run the command without powershell?

Comment: This was just an example.  I will actually use Powershell commands for some of the programming.  So which folder is the 64 bit powershell if this one isn't correct.  the SysWOW64 should be all the 64 bit version of the windows system.

Comment: @SDJ You got that backwards. WOW64 stands for Windows 32-bit on Win64 - when a 32-bit image accesses a file with the path `C:\Windows\System32\*`, the file system redirector checks if a corresponding 32-bit image exists in SysWOW64 and redirects the call. So, on 64-bit Windows: System32 = 64-bit images, SysWOW64 = 32-bit images

Comment: You are absolutely right!  I read up on that and the WOW64 is where they make 64bit applications compatible with 32 bit systems through a type of virtualization!  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc726001%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to specify the `Arguments` property *before* you start the process:

```
var newProcessInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
newProcessInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe";
newProcessInfo.Verb = "runas";
newProcessInfo.Arguments = @"sfc /scannow";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(newProcessInfo);
```

Second, you'll need to tell PowerShell that `sfc /scannow` is a command, and not command line switches.

On the command line you would do `powershell.exe -Command "sfc /scannow"`, so the correct `Arguments` value in your case would be

```
newProcessInfo.Arguments = @"-Command ""sfc /scannow""";
```

(`""` is the escape sequence for `"` in verbatim string literals)

For `.ps1` files, use the `-File` switch:

```
newProcessInfo.Arguments = @"-File ""C:\my\script.ps1""";
```

If you don't know the execution policy on the target system, you can bypass it without affecting the machine-wide policy with `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass`:

```
newProcessInfo.Arguments = @"–ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""C:\my\script.ps1""";
```

Comment: Thank you for all your knowledge!  This really helped me. :)