# How can I execute powershell script (as administrator) from C# Visual Studio and receive the result values?

Tags: c#, powershell, cmd

I need to execute powershell script AS ADMINISTRATOR from visual studio in C# and receive some result values about results of this execution back into Visual Studio.
What is the best way how to achive it?

Comment: Launch Visual Studio as administrator

Comment: It´s a bad practice to completely switch the context of a question after creation.

Answer (score 0):

Start the PowerShell as administrator or use this c# snippet:

```
ProcessStartInfo myProcess = new ProcessStartInfo(path);
myProcess.UserName = username;
myProcess.Password = MakeSecureString(password);
myProcess.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
```

Comment: No, i need to execute it from visual studio in C#, i edited it i only put it as a tag before, sorry.

Comment: Then you have to start your VS as administrator or use Start-Process in your script.

Comment: No. I need to do it as here for example but i need to get some result about execution back https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33509773/run-a-powershell-command-as-an-administrator-commands-themself-wont-load

Comment: That was not your initial question. I updated my answer.

Comment: This looks better :-) and would you even know how to do it so it automaticly run it as administrator even if current user was not administrator?

Comment: Check the answer.